# Are there UIScenes that are not UIWindowScenes?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ipados, ios-lifecycle

Apple's boilerplate code for UISceneDelegate contains a stub implementation for `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)`. This starts with:

```swift
guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
```

Is is really possible that we end up in the `else` branch here? The constructor of `UIScene` [mentions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscene/3197910-init)

> Subclasses call this method to initialize the scene details.

so my guess is that `UIScene` should be treated as an *abstract base class* that is never created directly, only from derived classes. But I didn't find any other classes derived from `UIScene`. If that holds true, wouldn't it make much more sense to write a *forced downcast* here?

```swift
scene as! UIWindowScene
```

Or is there a use case where it makes sense to create a user-defined subclass? If so, what would be an example for that and how would it be used?

Comment: Apple's sample code is much safer and more future-proof than simply assuming `scene` will always be a `UIWindowScene`. Maybe now all scenes are window scenes but maybe that could change in a future update to iOS.

Comment: @HangarRash I'd question that. If such a fundamental change came about, it's *highly* unlikely that just returning from the callback is the right thing to do. If we are lucky it leads to a crash somewhere else. Otherwise it can create a bug that might be hard to find. I'd always prefer an assertion failure (which the forced downcast would be) so I can easily find the spots I have to think about when editing the code for the iOS update in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Are there UIScenes that are not UIWindowScenes? Yes.
   CarPlay framework has its own `UIScene`, `UISceneDelegate`.

- `UIScene` : `CPTemplateApplicationDashboardScene`,  `CPTemplateApplicationScene`, `CPTemplateApplicationInstrumentClusterScene`
- `UISceneDelegate` : `CPTemplateApplicationSceneDelegate`, `CPTemplateApplicationDashboardSceneDelegate`, `CPTemplateApplicationInstrumentClusterSceneDelegate`

2. Is force casting is safe?
   Force casting is safe unless you share SceneDelegate with different [`Role`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscenesession/role).
   UIKit expects to have concrete subclass of `UIScene` for each `Role`.
   For example, `windowExternalDisplayNonInteractive`, `windowApplication`, `windowExternalDisplay` should connect to `UIWindowScene`.
3. Is there a use case where it makes sense to create a user-defined subclass?
   Rarely there could be, but using different `UISceneDelegate` for different `Role` is more preferred way.